# WebSocket and Rx Java

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I'm develop an android app that communicates with the server using a protocol WebSocket. I use AsyncAndroid lib. WebSocket has listener, that receive data from server.

Something like this

```
private WebSocket.StringCallback mStringCallback = new WebSocket.StringCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStringAvailable(String s) {

        }
    };
```

I need write api this, and i want use rxjava. But i cannot imagine, that should be Observable, and that Observer. i tried to do Observable string received from server into WebSocket listener, but i think it is bad idea.
Are there any ideas how correctly build api.
Thank u.

Comment: this source might help...https://github.com/jacek-marchwicki/JavaWebsocketClient/tree/master/websockets-rxjava-example

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap `WebSocket` into a new interface like this:

```
interface RxWebSocket {
    void send(byte[]); // send data
    Observable<String> stringObservable(); // receive string data
}
```

Then in a `RxWebSocket` implementation you can use `PublishSubject` with an internal `WebSocket.StringCallback` to publish the Strings.